# How to create a jar file without revealing my private data

Tags: java, jar

I wrote a Java program which **needs to read** a local source data file (the data is to large to be hard-coded into the program). Is it possible that I create a JAR package for the program without containing the local source data file (in order to keep the file private)? Or I have to encrypt the local file?

Comment: You can choose to put any resource you want or not into your JAR file, they're just a ZIP archive. If you don't want a file in there, don't add it in, and read it from the filesystem instead of using resources.

Comment: If the program needs the data file, how is not putting it in the JAR going to help? And if it doesn't need it, why would it go in the JAR in the first place?

Comment: the program needs to read the file

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't understand how leaving the file out of the JAR is going to keep it private.

Comment: That said, there are limits to how secure you can make this. Your private data **will** end up on the user's computer, so they can copy it anyway. And even if it's encrypted, your program has to decrypt it, so they can just use the keys you use. You'd have to obfuscate pretty much everything to deter even a somewhat skilled attacker (i.e. someone who can use a debugger and decompiler)

Comment: Basically, this sort of privacy can only be ensured on a sandboxed platform, and even there you have jailbreaks. If you don't want the user to access some data, just never send it to him. It's like the old chestnut where people ask you to make a website but want you to make it so people can't see the HTML or save the pictures on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real way to keep the file or data private. Not even encryption. If your program can read the data, then any one who has the same permissions as your program on that machine can read that data. At best you can make it a little inconvenient for someone to read the data - but you cannot prevent it.

If you encrypt the file - where will you keep the encryption key. If you program can read the encryption key, then a person also can. If you hardcode the encryption key in the program, then again the key can be got from the program binary.